# Почему не работает тег span

Tags: html, span

У меня html 5. Частично не работает код:`<a href="tel" id="popup__toggle"><span class="circlephone" style="transform-origin: center;"></span><span class="circle-fill" style="transform-origin: center;"></span><span class="img-circle" style="transform-origin: center;">**<SPAN class="img-circleblock" style="transform-origin: center;"></SPAN>**</span></a>` А именно не работает SPAN (в коде отличается заглавными буквами). `<SPAN class="img-circleblock" style="transform-origin: center;"></SPAN>` - Этот участок кода не работает если написан `span` и он отвечает за изображение телефонной трубки на странице html. Если поменять `span` на `<div>` то W3 валидатор определяет ошибку. Вот ссылка на код `css`:[код css](http://m.drevocolor.ru/buttons/handset.css) Я перепробовал комбинации всевозможных тегов методом тыка и помощью гугла, результат был такой- если изображение отображалось правильно, начинал ругаться валидатор, а если валидатор был доволен то изображение отображалось частично (телефонная трубка исчезала).
Вот ссылка на код `css`:[код css](http://m.drevocolor.ru/buttons/handset.css)
. Вот так ругается валидатор W3: `тип документа не позволяет использовать здесь элемент «div»; отсутствует один из "object",.........`
`Одна из возможных причин этого сообщения заключается в том, что вы попытались поместить элемент уровня блока (например, «<p>» или «<table>») внутри встроенного элемента (например, «<a>», «<span> "или" <font> ").`

Comment: Что значит «не работает»? И приведите всё необходимое для демонстрации проблемы прямо в тексте вопроса без сторонних ссылок, а пока ничего не понятно

Answer (score 1):

у тега `span` проблемы, когда нет текста внутри - тогда и с шириной проблемы и с прочими прелестями

поэтому или замените его на `div` (пофиг на ошибки) или выставите свойство `display: inline-block`

```
.img-circleblock{
display: inline-block;
/*тут остальные ваши стили*/
}
```

P.S.

кстати вместо этой связки

```
<a href="#"><span class="img-circleblock" style="transform-origin: center;"></span></a>
```

можно же сделать эту:

```
<a href="#" class="img-circleblock" style="transform-origin: center;"></a>
```

при условии конечно, то будет указан `display: inline-block`

P.P.S.

кстати я прогнал ваш код через валидатор и на `div` он не ругался
поэтому лучше если бы вы и саму ошибку привели бы

Comment: Спасибо. Валидатор ругается на div в этом коде: <a href="tel:" id="popup__toggle"><span class="circlephone" style="transform-origin: center;"></span><span class="circle-fill" style="transform-origin: center;"></span><span class="img-circle" style="transform-origin: center;"><div class="img-circleblock" style="transform-origin: center;"></div></span></a>

Comment: @Sergun, Это потому что вы хотите впихнуть невпихуемое, засунуть в коробку шкаф :) - у вас `div` внутри `span`, браузеры это переварят, но `span` не для этих целей - не надо его так использовать :)

Comment: Спасибо  Zhihar.! Только как заставить правильно работать элемент, чтобы все были довольны?  Остаётся только это - "поэтому или замените его на div (пофиг на ошибки) или выставите свойство display: inline-block" :-)

Comment: @Sergun - я же написал выше 2 выхода 1) замените `span` на `div` и добавьте css свойство `display: inline-block` (y `span` оно `diplay: inline` отсюда и проблемы) 2) вообще откажитесь от `span/div` внутри `<a></a>`, но самому тегу `a` назначьте  соответствующий класс, и опять же css стиль для класса `display: inline-block`. Вообще `display: inine-block` - это и есть решение вашей проблемы

Comment: Спасибо. Так и буду делать.

Comment: Zhihar! Сделал как вы сказали - оставил `span` и выставил свойство `display: inline-block` 

`.img-circleblock{
display: inline-block;
/*тут остальные ваши стили*/
}` Всё заработало и W3 зелёненький )) Так просто!!!   Дай Бог Вам здоровья.

Comment: @Sergun, вообще `span` от `div` отличается тем, что `span` - это `display: inline`, а `div` - `display: block`, если вы `display: ***` устанавливаете сами, то для браузера уже не имеет значение как этот тег назывался изначально, поэтому лучше использовать `div` - он на 1 букву короче :)))